# TelegramBot Webhook is set, but it doesn't work

Tags: php, ssl, webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot

I have some questions about setting the Webhook in `TelegramBot`. At first I followed a YouTube tutorial. I hosted free webspace at [lima-city.de (lang-DE)](https://www.lima-city.de/) with an SSL certificate and set the Webhook with
https://api.telegram.org/bot183900136:AAEk7QYske1vtpl9GlR_-7KMye2g6jMfynQ/setwebhook?url=https://telegram-bot.lima-city.de/helloworld.php

Is used the following code:

```
$botToken = "MyBotToken";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=217296540&text=hi");
```

But my Bot doesn't react to my messages. Here are some tips from `TelegramBot`:

1. You will not be able to receive updates using `getUpdates` for as long as an outgoing Webhook is set up.
2. To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your public key certificate using certificate parameter. Please upload as `InputFile`, sending a String will not work.
3. Ports currently supported for Webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443.

I don't know what I could do next to solve the problem.

Comment: What file_get_contents return? Print it.
Цell, I would use the sdk (https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)

Comment: Have you just put on the web your private API key for the bot?

Comment: Yes but it is now fixed

Comment: hi, how did you fix it @JokerJoe